# Would it be better to parse HTML on the server with PHP or on the end user side with JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, web-scraping

I need to write a script that takes a link and parses the HTML of the linked page to pull in the title and a few other pieces of data like potentially a short description much like when you link to something on Facebook.

It will be called when a user adds a link to the site, so could see a decent number of hits when the client launches the site.

I am curious if I should do this on the server side with PHP or the end user side with Javascript? I have been writing the logic behind trying to figure out which areas of the markup are filled with potential content and it made me wonder if the load would be too much if I continue in PHP.

The client has just the one decent web server and I worry parsing/analyzing HTML pages may be too much load where we could do it in Javascript and farm it out to the user adding the link.

Any advice or thoughts on the matter would be awesome. Thank you.

Edit: This data is not going straight into the database, it is used to help the user by auto filling the description of their link which still goes through my regular vetting before being stored to the DB.

Comment: Commenting instead of answering, because this is opinion:  If the "load" is too much for a PHP script on the server, it would probably perform even worse on the client.  Take into account that you cannot predict the environment or resources of the client, and I would go PHP all day over JavaScript.

Comment: @Stephen - as PHP is compiled into bytecode, it will run much faster than JS. Also, there are a (very small) percentage of browsers with JS turned off.

Comment: Except that your php code runs on a single server for all clients, your js runs on each client separately

Comment: The scraping will be fast on JS or PHP. My concern is that if thousands of people are adding links, will the PHP version bog down with tons of people asking it to pull in and parse all these pages.

Comment: Thousands is not a problem. Not at all.  It's the number of *concurrent* requests that can create performance problems.  So unless you mean "thousands per second" (which you don't) then you'll be fine.  Even a thousand a minute (which you won't get except maybe in bursts) is only 16.7 per second - pretty trivial to achieve on a webserver.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is an easy one, because performing this from the client-side purely with JavaScript just plain isn't an option at all due to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Parsing HTML isn't that heavy of a task, you should be fine doing it in PHP.

Comment: I don't think there will be much of an issue with the same origin policy. The JS on my site will just pull in one pages markup via an iframe or similar method so that the request would be no different than a regular page load. And worst case, the user would just not get the pre population benefit.

Comment: Also, yeah. My concern was the load of running searches on the HTML to rate content areas along with the potential requests to servers bogging the system down.

Comment: The other perk would be that the JavaScript version would not look like my server was constantly requesting pages from another site. It would come from the user's browser that wants to link to that site.

Comment: "The JS on my site will just pull in one pages markup via an iframe or similar method so that the request would be no different than a regular page load." Have you actually tried doing this yet?  Get back to me after you've written some code.

Answer (score 0):

I would offload this to the end-user via javascript, with a listener you could then bind it back to the server.  The reasons why are simple:

- This is a helper to the front-end not the backend (values aren't stored or manipulated on the backend directly.)
- The load is better spread around than localized on your server, also you'll probably give a better user experience here if the end-user is only pulling 1 url vs. the server pulling thousands.
- Processing in the front-end also mitigates the possibility of malicious code being executed directly on your server.

Answer (score 0):

If you're thinking about having the client actually got and fetch some random site, parse it for you in Javascript, grab the title, description and other data and then submit that in your form for you, your form's submit time is going to be held hostage to your user's network connection speed for fetching that page and whatever overhead (likely miniscule) for parsing the data. If you do that server side using cURL, the hit will be in parsing the document for what you need. the best speed solution would probably be to let the person enter the URL, get it back in PHP, have PHP hand it off to a Perl script (which has some wicked fast DOM parsers) and get the required data back for the PERL script. From personal experience, the Perl scripts outperform cURL all day long, and cURL generally outperforms javascript AJAX gets by a wide margin just by nature of being on a bigger pipe than a home user.

Comment: The JS for pulling in the data would be done later so that it would not hang the form for the user. The last thing I want to do is slow down anything for a user that knows exactly what they want.

Answer (score 0):

You can do both....

1) PHP:

- checkout [HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/), could be helpful
- or use php curl and then parse with DOMDocument

2) JavaScript:

- you don't have to bother your server (pro)
- parsing content with jQuery is easy (pro)
- you need to handle cross domain policy (cons)

Comment: I know I can do both, just trying to figure out which will be better for the user experience. Do not want to slow down my server if handling these would be to big of a load.